# How to Get and filter Data attribute of all parents in a nested list, till a target (div) of html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested-lists, parents

I've a nested (UL->LI->UL-LI..) list. On any clicked node, I'm using ParentsUntil() to find all the parents till a certain ancestor element.

In each nested element's data attribute (data-weight:), there is number that represent weight.

I want to sum/aggregate total weight till the parent. These numbers (Areas) are in the data-area field of each item.

```
<ul class="level-1 yes"  data-weight="12" data-weight-total="0">
  <li class="item-i" data-weight="22" >I</li>
  <li class="item-ii" data-weight="4"  data-weight-total="0">II
    <ul class="level-2 yes" data-weight="12">
      <li class="item-a" data-weight="1.4">A</li>
      <li class="item-b" data-weight="128" data-weight-total="0">B
        <ul class="level-3" data-weight="63" data-weight-total="0">
          <li class="item-1" data-weight="54">1</li>
          <li class="item-2" data-weight="23">2</li>
          <li class="item-3" data-weight="107">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c" data-weight="231">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>



    $( "li.item-2" )
       .parentsUntil( $( "ul.level-1" ), ".yes" );
```

In the list above,

1. How can I get the an array/list of them items from the clicked item
   to the parent item with their `data-weight` [key,value]? for e.g. $VarArrayCargoVessel
2. And as I traverse up, How can I sum/total weights (data-weight-total) of *each*/nested list and populate\fill-in the `data-weight-total`? I have zero's right now, because I dont know how to insert/write into a array value

Comment: Can you add a sample of what your HTML looks like and your expected result?

Comment: As @dotnetom asked, can you also provide what is the expected result you want to get, not sure your question is clear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm unclear about which parents you actually want to select to calculate total weight - your current example would only return '<ul class="level-2 yes" data-weight="12">' on $("li.item-2"). Also which children do you want to take into account while calculating the data-weight-total attribute?

Comment: Thanks for ignoring my answer.

Comment: @oddDev I'm not ignoring anything, the website says I cannot comment or edit for 24 hrs! Actually a very good answer, I am trying to figure out how and where you wrote the summed values, i.e. which data attribute. I am also trying to collect that and post back to server via AJAX (So I want to access the summed values too)

Comment: @Crew I'm really sorry :$ Thought you have been gone forever :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("li").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  var list = $(this).closest("ul");
  var children = list.children();
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    values.push(parseInt((children[i].getAttribute("data-weight") !== null) ? children[i].getAttribute("data-weight") : "0"));
  }
  var sum = 0;
  for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
    sum += values[j];
  }
  $("#summed").html(sum);
});
```

```css
li{
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level-1 yes"  data-weight="12" data-weight-total="0">
  <li class="item-i" data-weight="22" >I</li>
  <li class="item-ii" data-weight="4"  data-weight-total="0">II
    <ul class="level-2 yes" data-weight="12">
      <li class="item-a" data-weight="1.4">A</li>
      <li class="item-b" data-weight="128" data-weight-total="0">B
        <ul class="level-3" data-weight="63" data-weight-total="0">
          <li class="item-1" data-weight="54">1</li>
          <li class="item-2" data-weight="23">2</li>
          <li class="item-3" data-weight="107">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c" data-weight="231">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>

<div id="summed"></div>
```

Okay, let's get through this step by step. The first thing we do is creating a click event for each "li" item. If a li item is clicked, we execute our function ("function(event)").

The first line stops the event from propagating up. jQuery would go up to the very first "ul" item otherwise and execute the code for each "ul" element. We would receive the first list all the time.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

We then get the closest "ul" element and store this in the variable "list". We don't want the list itself, that's why we store its children ("li" elements) in the variable "children".

We loop then through each children and store the "data-weight" attribute (method "getAttribute") in the array "values". Note that we only store the attribute if it's actually exists. If not, we just store "0".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

We then create a variable "sum" which stores our summed up attributes. To do so we loop through the array and add the value (+= values[j]) to the sum variable.

The last step writes the sum variable in the html of the div with the id #summed (check the html section).

Further reading:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute
http://api.jquery.com/closest/
http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
http://api.jquery.com/children/
http://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/
http://api.jquery.com/html/
```

Version 2:

```js
$("li").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  var list = $(this).find("ul").first();
  console.log(list);
  var children = list.children();
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    values.push(parseInt((children[i].getAttribute("data-weight") !== null) ? children[i].getAttribute("data-weight") : "0"));
  }
  var sum = 0;
  for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
    sum += values[j];
  }
  $("#summed").html(sum);
});
```

```css
li{
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level-1 yes"  data-weight="12" data-weight-total="0">
  <li class="item-i" data-weight="22" >I</li>
  <li class="item-ii" data-weight="4"  data-weight-total="0">II
    <ul class="level-2 yes" data-weight="12">
      <li class="item-a" data-weight="1.4">A</li>
      <li class="item-b" data-weight="128" data-weight-total="0">B
        <ul class="level-3" data-weight="63" data-weight-total="0">
          <li class="item-1" data-weight="54">1</li>
          <li class="item-2" data-weight="23">2</li>
          <li class="item-3" data-weight="107">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c" data-weight="231">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>

<div id="summed"></div>
```

Note the third line in the answer. I've changed it to:

```
var list = $(this).find("ul").first();
```

Version 3:

```js
$("li").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  var children = $(this).find("ul").first().children();
  if(children.length === 0){
    children = $(this);
  }
  console.log(children);
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    values.push(parseFloat((children[i].getAttribute("data-weight") !== null) ? children[i].getAttribute("data-weight") : "0"));
  }
  var sum = 0;
  for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
    sum += values[j];
  }
  $("#summed").html(sum);
});
```

```css
li{
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level-1 yes"  data-weight="12" data-weight-total="0">
  <li class="item-i" data-weight="22" >I</li>
  <li class="item-ii" data-weight="4"  data-weight-total="0">II
    <ul class="level-2 yes" data-weight="12">
      <li class="item-a" data-weight="1.4">A</li>
      <li class="item-b" data-weight="128" data-weight-total="0">B
        <ul class="level-3" data-weight="63" data-weight-total="0">
          <li class="item-1" data-weight="54">1</li>
          <li class="item-2" data-weight="23">2</li>
          <li class="item-3" data-weight="107">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c" data-weight="231">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>

<div id="summed"></div>
```

Comment: Yes this is the functionality, but the script does not total correctly. If you click on Node A and C they show the totals of Node B. A is 1.4 and C is 231, both show 360 as totals, which is not correct, _should be 1.4 and 231, since they have no nodes_.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really get it. What the script does is: A + B + C as integer. That means it sums up: 1+128+231 = 360. The script always goes to the parent "ul" element and sums up the li children. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Imagine A, B, and C are cargo trucks, only Truck B should have 360 weight 1) Data-total-weight = totals of childrens Data-total-weight only. i.e. Totals at every `li` and `ul` only the `totals of its immediate children`.

2) But even **items/li/ul/nodes without children** are getting totals from adjacent nodes. For e.g. A and C do not have children, but they are showing 360. Only B should have 360 total, because the children's weight belong to it. 

3) Same thing again at node `ii` `<li class="item-ii"` has children, so it should only _show = A + B + C since they are nested under ii_

Comment: @Crew check the second version in my answer. Does this work like expected?

Comment: This works perfect. Can I ask, for lists/trucks that don't have children/cargo, in the script how can I use an option `var onEmptyShowTruckWeight = true` to either show their own data-weight as total weight, for e.g selecting `A would show 1.4 and selecting C would show 231`.   (The user finds 0 weight for trucks sometimes confusing and wants to see weight on the empty trucks)

Comment: I'll add this as Version 3... Give me a second :)

Comment: @Crew Done :) Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following jQuery methods, they are all you need:

- `each` ([link](https://api.jquery.com/each/)),
- `attr` ([link](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)),
- `find` ([link](https://api.jquery.com/find/)) / `children` ([link](https://api.jquery.com/children/))

For example, at page load, you want to find each node that has a `data-weight-total` attribute, go through all its (immediate or all) children that have a `data-weight` attribute, get the sum of them and assign it to the node's `data-weight-total` property. If you want only immediate children, you would use `.children()`, or for all you would use `.find()`:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ // DOM ready

    $('[data-weight-total]').each(function(){ 

        var total = 0;

        $(this).find('[data-weight]').each(function(){
            total = total + parseInt($(this).attr('data-weight'));
        });

        $(this).attr('data-weight-total',total);

    });
})
```

This would calculate and assign `data-weight-total` values to all nodes that have such an attribute, as soon as the document is loaded. Let me know if you need explanations for any of what's going on in the function.

Comment: wow this approach is a lot easier to read :)  I'm trying this with the .find() will let you know if it works. I can not upvote your answer...  says not enough reputation..